# Restart Debugging in VS Code does not save current file [Mac]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have been using VS Code for Python scripting and for running the script I use the commands:

1. **Run without debugging:**
   `Option` + `cmd` + `B`
2. **Restart Debugging:**
   `Option` + `cmd` + `M`

Restart Debugging is specially useful since it stops the running and restart the process with the *Current File*, i.e. the file in my active window/tab.

However, since I updated to VS Code `1.70.1`, I noticed that the *Current File* does not get “saved” when I Restart Debugging. In other words, if I modify something in the file and I restart debugging I would expect that the new script will run with the modifications that I just did, instead, it does not. It runs the script with the latest saved configuration.

How can I change the configuration of the command **Restart Debugging** to save my *Current File* before running?

I understand that one alternative would be to turn on the `AutoSave`, but I was wondering if I could just continue using Restart Debugging as I was in VS Code `1.69`.

Note: I am using a Mac but I imagine that this set up is similar for other OS.

Comment: Reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157655.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, change your **Debug: Save Before Start** to `allEditorsInActiveGroup` like the following picture:

[image]

Comment: This does not work for the "Restart Debugging" only for the direct "Run without debugging"

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved in this PR of VSCode.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158184

However, it is still in an ureleased version.